# Array of Objects and Marker Data

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use my array of objects to create markers in the maps api.

I am trying to pass the results into an array to do a listview of the objects and their properties later.

Right now I have trouble generating the markers from the array data.

Any ideas?

Also the value of that console.log is 1.

```
function callback(results, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          console.log(results[i]);
          var arr =[];
          allResults = arr.push(results[i]);
          console.log(allResults);
          createMarker(allResults);
          }
        }
      }


    function createMarker(place) {
      var placeLoc = allResults.place.geometry.location;
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: allResults.place.geometry.location
      });
```

Comment: What does your array look like?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.  From the posted code, I would expect an obvious error message in the javascript console...

Comment: The value of the console.log is 1

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: Geocode, I appreciate that you are willing to help. Now, I'm not sure what your line of work is but mine is sales management. A more effective way of coaching others is explaining how I need to amend my post. This is the second post of mine you have down voted and then copied and pasted the rules. I want help and I know I won't get it until I follow the rules. But, I have done the same thing twice now, so maybe I'm not sure what you are getting at by copy and pasting the rules. Can you please be more specific? I really do appreciate it.

Comment: Bottom line: If I knew what you wanted to be able to help me, I would have done it already because I want help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many mistakes here I think
1) what is all result here is it a global variable than why are you passing it to createmaker and catching it as a place and again using allresult.place
2) if allresult is an array how you can access allresult.place like this Loop it again all result[I].place